# Optimizing a Prime Number Factorization algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, factorization

The following below is an algorithm that finds the prime factorization for a given number N.  I'm wondering if there are any ways to make this faster using HUGE numbers.  I'm talking like 20-35 digit numbers.  I wanna try and get these to go as fast as possible.  Any ideas?

```
import time

def prime_factors(n):
    """Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
    factors = []
    divisor = 2        
    while n > 1:        
        while n % divisor == 0:
            factors.append(divisor)
            n /= divisor          
        divisor = divisor + 1
        if divisor*divisor > n:
            if n > 1: 
                factors.append(n)
            break
    return factors

#HUGE NUMBERS GO IN HERE!
start_time = time.time()
my_factors = prime_factors(15227063669158801)
end_time = time.time()
print my_factors
print "It took ", end_time-start_time, " seconds."
```

Comment: What time are you getting for the above number?

Comment: Less than a second.  But for some 20 digit numbers and above, it take more than 30 seconds!

Comment: instead of incrementing `divisor` by 1 each time, you could iterate over the primes instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268526/non-distinct-prime-factors-of-larger-numbers

Comment: First of all, avoid appending. This takes time because each time you append to a list, it has to be reallocated in memory, which takes time. This could be solved by preallocating a list to a specified size (I believe that the post above touches upon this) - you'll have to figure out the maximum prime factors in a number. Also, rather than increasing divisor by one, set it to the next prime.

Comment: @JacobKudria: Most of the time, appending to a list does not require a resize. The list size scales in such a way that appending N items takes combined time O(N). Preallocating can sometimes save time, but not much.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Prime_decomposition#Python

Comment: @ user2357112 Thanks. I was always told that I should preallocate, but if it doesn't save much time then...

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is trial division, which has time complexity O(sqrt(n)). You can improve your algorithm by using only 2 and the odd numbers as trial divisors, or even better by using only prime numbers as trial divisors, but the time complexity will remain O(sqrt(n)).

To go faster you need a better algorithm. Try this:

```
def factor(n, c):
    f = lambda(x): (x*x+c) % n
    t, h, d = 2, 2, 1
    while d == 1:
        t = f(t); h = f(f(h)); d = gcd(t-h, n)
    if d == n:
        return factor(n, c+1)
    return d
```

To call it on your number, say

```
print factor(15227063669158801, 1)
```

That returns the (possibly composite) factor 2090327 virtually instantly. It uses an algorithm called the *rho* algorithm, invented by John Pollard in 1975. The rho algorithm has time complexity O(sqrt(sqrt(n))), so it's much faster than trial division.

There are many other algorithms for factoring integers. For numbers in the 20 to 35 digit range that interests you, the elliptic curve algorithm is well-suited. It should factor numbers of that size in no more than a few seconds. Another algorithm that is well-suited to such numbers, especially those that are semi-primes (have exactly two prime factors), is SQUFOF.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend [this essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) on my blog. When you're finished with that, other entries on my blog talk about elliptic curve factorization, and SQUFOF, and various other even more-powerful methods of factoring ever-larger integers.

Comment: TD on primes is ~ 2sqrt(n)/log(n) I think.

Comment: I think you're right, but on the range of n where trial division makes sense, the factor of log(n) doesn't matter very much, especially as you only get half of it, so it makes some sense to think of trial division as an O(sqrt(n)) algorithm no matter how you implement it (odds, 2,3,5-wheel, primes). At least, I always do.

Comment: empirically I get only half of that half, but a speedup of 6.8x is still noticeable :) (TD factorization on primes vs on odds, discounting the primes generation). And for 1 more digit, it's 7.2x. So I think of it as "slightly better than sqrt(n)". "Much" better would mean speedups of thousands or millions of course. It means I can use TD for about two more digits, with primes. -- (Also, I tried your code with a prime number... :) )

Comment: @WIllNess: (regarding your parenthetical comment) If you try to factor a prime number you deserve whatever you get.

Comment: But I wasn't warned!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, list all prime factorization for a number 100.

- Check **2** is one of factorizations or not. And then, 2 < 2*c <= 100 could be removed. Ex, 4, 6, 8, ... 98
- Check **3** is one of factorizations or not. And then, 3 < 2*d <= 100 could be removed. Ex, 9, 12, ... 99
- **4** is removed from possible set.
- Check **5**, And then, 10, 15, 20, ..., 100 are removed.
- **6** is removed.
- Check **7**, ....
  ....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no check for divisors. Sorry if I am wrong but how do you know if divisor is prime or not? Your divisor variable is increasing by 1 after each loop so I assume it will generate a lot of composite numbers.

Answer (score 0):

No optimizations to that algorithm will allow you to factor 35 digit numbers at least in the general case. The reason is that the number of primes up to 35 digits are too high to be listed in a reasonable amount of time let alone attempt to divide by each one. Even if one was inclined to try, the number of bits required to store them would be far too much as well. In this case you'll want to select a different algorithm from the list of [general purpose factorization algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#General-purpose).

However, if all the prime factors are small enough (say below 10^12 or so), then you could use a segmented [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), or simply find a list of primes up to some practical number (say 10^12 or so) online and use that instead of trying to calculate the primes and hope the list is large enough.